# Use type, which is imported behind feature flag, even if feature flag isn't enabled

Tags: rust

Here's my Cargo.toml:

```ini
[package]
name = "tmp"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
chrono = "0.4.24"
chrono-tz = {version="0.8.2", optional = true}

[features]
my_feature = ["chrono-tz"]
```

Here's my `src/main.rs`:

```rust
#[cfg(feature = "some_feature")]
use chrono_tz::Tz;

#[cfg(feature = "some_feature")]
fn my_fn(tz: Tz){
    println!("tz is: {:?}", tz);
}


fn feature_function(tz: Option<Tz>) {
    match tz {
        #[cfg(feature = "some_feature")]
        Some(tz) => my_fn(tz),
        _ => (),
    }
}

fn main() {
    feature_function(None);
}
```

Note how `feature_function` takes a `tz: Optional<Tz>`, but that the `Some(tz)` case is only reached when "some_feature" is enabled.

So, if I don't have "some_feature" enabled, I'd like to be able to call `feature_function` with `tz=None`.

Predictably, this doesn't compile:

```rust
error[E0412]: cannot find type `Tz` in this scope
  --> src/main.rs:10:32
   |
10 | fn feature_function(tz: Option<Tz>) {
   |                                ^^ not found in this scope
   |
help: you might be missing a type parameter
   |
10 | fn feature_function<Tz>(tz: Option<Tz>) {
   |                    ++++

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0412`.
error: could not compile `tmp` due to previous error
```

Is there some trick I can use to type `tz` in `feature_function`, so that if "some_feature" isn't enabled, then I can still call `feature_function` with `tz=None`?

Comment: Instead of using `#[cfg(feature = "some_feature")]` on the branch, you could duplicate your function, using `#[cfg(feature = "some_feature")]` on one of them and `#[cfg(not(feature = "some_feature)")]`, then change the argument to `Option<Inhabited>` to the featureless one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To determine the size of a `Option<T>` the compiler has to know `T` so if the function has to have the same signature across features you *have to* import `Tz` in both cases.
If the same signature is not necessary you can define 2 different functions with the same name:

```rust
enum NeedSomeFeatureForTz{}
#[cfg(not(feature = "some_feature"))]
fn feature_function(tz: Option<NeedSomeFeatureForTz>) {
    match tz {
        _ => (),
    }
}
#[cfg(feature = "some_feature")]
fn feature_function(tz: Option<Tz>) {
    match tz {
        Some(tz) => my_fn(tz),
        _ => (),
    }
}
```